# How to access `this` object in callback function inside prototype method?

Tags: javascript

I want to use `this` in a callback function in a prototype method eg.:

```
String.prototype.new= function (data) {
    'use strict';
    //here I can use 'this'
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).forEach(function (d) {
        //here I want to use 'this' but I can't
    });
};
```

See the comments above: How do I use `this` within the callback?

Comment: Sorry for that, question's changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach` accepts a second argument, which tells it what to use for `this` during the callbacks, so:

```
String.prototype.new= function (data) {
    'use strict';
    //...
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).forEach(function (d) {
        //...
    }, this);
//   ^^^^^^--------------- added
};
```

Almost all of the *new* ES5 `Array` methods have that `thisArg` argument.

If you were using something that *didn't* have an argument it used that way (for instance, the old `Array#sort` function), you could use a variable you save `this` to and then use the variable in the callback:

```
String.prototype.new= function (data) {
    'use strict';
    var thisString = this;

    //...
    someArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        // use `thisString` here
    });
};
```